# Accessing pointers inside class

Tags: c++

i am trying to use a pointer variable in a class but instead it gave me an error

Car.cpp:15:16: error: right hand operand to ->* has non-pointer-to-member type 'int *'
return this->*tires;

here is my program

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x = 5;
    Car honda("honda", &x);
    
    cout << honda.getBrand() << " " << honda.getTires() << endl;
    x = 6;
    cout << honda.getBrand() << " " << honda.getTires() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Car.h

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Car {
    private:
        string brand;
        int *tires;
    public:
        Car(string brand, int *tires);
        string getBrand();
        int getTires();
};

#endif
```

Car.cpp

```
#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;

Car::Car(string brand, int *tires){
    this->brand = brand;
    this->tires = tires;
}

string Car::getBrand(){
    return this->brand;
}

int Car::getTires(){
    return this->*tires;
}
```

on Car.cpp the method Car::getTires lies the error which seems to already be logical, i tried to use this->tires or this->(*tires) but it still gave me error.

Comment: Try doing it without the `this` in the method. Or try `*(this->tires)`;

Comment: `return *(this->tires)`

Comment: *(this->tires) is what i'm trying to find. thx it now works, @DrewDormann fair enough..

Comment: If you consider your problem solved, please select the answers who helped you most and click the green checkmark button beneath it. That way, others will know that you no longer require aid.

Comment: A bit out of context, but remember that `int Car::getTires()` could be `int * Car::getTires()` and you could dereference the returned pointer => like this everyone using your class will call `Tires`as pointers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire variable is called `this->tires`, the `this` referring to the current object and the `tires` referring to the member itself.

As such, you need to dereference the variable and not 'a part of it`.

Either use:

```
int Car::getTires(){
    return *tires;
}
```

which works, because the `this` is implied automatically by the compiler or

```
int Car::getTires(){
    return *(this->tires);
}
```

`return *this->tires;` should also work, because the operator precedence puts the `->` before the `*` (meaning it first evaluates the this prior to trying dereferencing the variable). (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 3):

This is a syntax error. `->*` or `.*` if for *pointer to members* which are quite different animals (more on [cppreferences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer))

Here you just have a member which happens to be a pointer. You can simply dereference it with `*tires` or `*this->tires`.